# tomcat6 sqlite3 user authentication

Tags: sqlite, tomcat, jdbc, user-management

I was wondering how one would go about using sqlite3 to validate users in tomcat6.
I do not have permission to install any sql type services, so I have to depend on sqlite3. My hope was to add this as a wrapper to an already existing deployment to provide better user management.

I have a `users.db` (tables: `users(username,password)`, `roles(username,role)`) file sitting right next to `tomcat-users.xml` in `/etc/tomcat6`. I tried (unsuccessfully) to edit `server.xml` with this:

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    description="User database that can be updated and saved"
    driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
    pathname="conf/log.db" />

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
    resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

Additionally, I got a JDBC driver `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar` for sqlite3 from http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/ and placed it in `CATALINA_HOME` (it is specifically at `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated from this frustrated Tomcat noobie. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to depend on sqlite3. You could use [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html) which was written in Java and does not require any platform specific binaries. Another candidate is [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) and maybe there are some others.

Comment: Well, it turns out the target machine this will go on will have mysql, so the problem is phased out. Apparently there is no native tomcat sqlite3 support, so I was going down the wrong path as you were saying. Thank you for your answer!